Prove $a^b+b^a\leq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$
Prove $a^b+b^a\leq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$, if $a+b=1$ and $a>0,b>0$.
It seems quite difficult for me to use the naive differentiation method (e.g. take $f(x)=a^{\frac{1}{2}-x}+b^{\frac{1}{2}+x}$ and try to prove $f'(x)<0$) to prove it.
It also reminds me of Jensen inequality, however, I don't know to apply it specifically.
Any help is appreciated.

@Gary Yes, it seems this problem has been posted, but I suspect there are more elegant solutions.
